# Custom ProgressBar in notification Android studio

Tags: android-studio

Is there any way to implement a custom progress bar in the notification?

Like a circular progress bar.

Comment: Seems no. But why? Standard PB is good

Comment: I know standard PB is good . But  it was my query to know about this. Now i have found that there are too many limitations here...
By the way thanks for your  comment ...